# How to set up a cron job for ffmpeg in centOS 6

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, cron, imagick

I can convert from mp4 file to jpg file manually one by one with the below command on centOS 6 environment.

Now, could anyone help me out how to set up a cron for any mp4 file in the directory to be converted automatically 
to jpg file with the same file name as mp4 file such as `03052022_5a9d28723d2da.jpg` for the below environment?

OS：centos-6 (x86_64)

ffmpeg version 2.2.2

Plesk 17.0.17

```
[root@server-xxxxxxxx-x ~]# ffmpeg -i                                \
  /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/03052022_5a9d28723d2da.mp4 \
  /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/03052022_5a9d28723d2da.jpg
```

With 's/.conf$/.jpg/p':

```
[root@server-xxxxxx-x ~]# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En 's/.conf$/.jpg/p'`; done
```

ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 21 2018 03:03:24 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
     configuration:
     libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
     libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
     libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
     libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
     libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
     libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
     libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
     Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from   '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/03081956_5aa116c836015.mp4':
     Metadata:
      major_brand     : mp42
      minor_version   : 0
      compatible_brands: isommp42
      creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
      Duration: 00:00:00.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23270 kb/s
       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc,   smpte170m), 1920x1080, 25370 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 29.73 fps, 30 tbr, 90k   tbn, 180k tbc (default)
         Metadata:
         rotate          : 90
         creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
         handler_name    : VideoHandle
         Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
         Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
          handler_name    : SoundHandle
       At least one output file must be specified
       Conversion failed!

With "s/.conf$/.jpg/p":

```
[root@server-xxxxxxx-x ~]# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En "s/.conf$/.jpg/p"`; done
```

ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 21 2018 03:03:24 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration:
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/03081956_5aa116c836015.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
  Duration: 00:00:00.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23270 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 1920x1080, 25370 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 29.73 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-14 04:42:34
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
At least one output file must be specified
Conversion failed!

With "s/.mp4$/.jpg/p"

```
[root@server-xxxxx-x ~]# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En "s/.mp4$/.jpg/p"`; done
```

[image2 @ 0x2c488e0] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/03100013_5aa2a49bb67bc.jpg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=3.2 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=N/A
video:289kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.007446%
Conversion failed!

Comment: Use crontab? Like you just need to setup the command and drew

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm not really familiar with ffmpeg cron job on centos and I'd appreciate if you could show me an example for the above case.

Comment: It’s the same as setting crontab for everything else

Comment: The error comes from the sed command. Can you try to change the last option from /P to /p?

Comment: Thanks OldC, So, that was my mistake to use the upper case P, and I appreciated you to find such a tiny mistake. I've tried and posted the result. It has reduced error messages, but kept to show "At least one output file must be specified " .

Comment: Seems your sed command output empty string. What is .conf$ inside the sed argument means? Do you mean a variable $conf? If it is the case, you cannot put variable inside a single quote string. Change to double quote instead.

Comment: Thanks, OldC, I've tried with "s/.conf$/.jpg/p" and had the same kind of error. Did I do all right?

Comment: If you simply want to replace .mp4 with .jpg then simple change the command to "s/.mp4$/.jpg/p".

Comment: Thanks, OldC, I need to remain mp4 file and create jpg file from the mp4 in the directory.

Comment: Thanks, OldC, and sorry to be long. I'd like to apply the cron job every time new mp4 file is created in the directory only for newly created mp4 file instead of all the mp4 file in the directory. So, would it be possible to convert only one mp4 file that is just created in the directory to jpg file instead of converting all the mp4 file by using "*.mp4"? 
If it is so and then, how should I change the command line?

Comment: OldC, With "s/.mp4$/.jpg/p", I finally could get jpg file with the same name as mp4 file even though I had an error. I posted it, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command which will convert all `.mp4` to `.jpg` in the mentioned directory:

```
# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En 's/.conf$/.jpg/p'`; done
```

If you want to delete source `.mp4` file upon the conversion, expand it as follows:

```
# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En 's/.conf$/.jpg/p'`; rm -f $i; done
```

You can schedule this command as a regular cron job or via **Tools & Settings > Scheduled Tasks > Add Task** in Plesk.
I executed the command string of the same complexity just now and it works as expected:[image]

Comment: Thanks Elvis, It is running as many mp4 file as I have for the directory, but not creating any jpg file in the directory saying that "At least one output file must be specified" at the bottom.  I've attached it on the top.

Comment: I'm trying to find what is wrong here. Have I done anything wrong with the settings?

Comment: Elvis, Thanks for your explanation about scheduling a task and Now, I'd like to use "Run a PHP script" as a cron job that runs automatically only after mp4 file was created in the directory. How should I use the command that you gave me in this case? Should I use it inside PHP file? I mean that I'd like to run the command every time mp4 file is created in the directory without deleting the rest of mp4 files, only for the new mp4 file, not for all the file like *.mp4. Meanwhile I'm working on the error "At least one output file must be specified".